# if constexpr in a recursive generic lambda: different compiler behavior

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17, if-constexpr

The following code [compiles successfully with *g++ 7.3.0* and fails to compile with *clang++ 6.0.0*](https://godbolt.org/g/7fGCpr) (compilation flags are `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
auto foo = [](auto, auto... tail) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) > 0)
    {
        return foo(tail...);
    }
    else
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

*clang++* compilation error message:

> error: variable 'foo' declared with deduced type 'auto' cannot appear in its own initializer
>
> ```
> return foo(tail...);
> ```

What behavior is standard compliant in this case?

Comment: i don't see how it can compile because foo isn't captured (and can't be captured)

Comment: @Tyker There is no need to capture global objects like `foo` in this example.

Comment: The 2017 paper [p0839r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0839r0.html) proposes a change to the C++ grammar to allow a self-referential name in a lambda's declaration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clang is right to reject this according to [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#10), as of C++17.

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

The type of `foo` is needed to resolve the recursive call (find `operator()`, etc). It's needed to determine the closure type. Since the closure type is being deduced here... you see where it goes.

GCC may prove it's not always impossible to get around it, but in general the standard prohibits it.

Comment: And what about [the similar code with the usual template function](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oZJsTDc1LLjzNexk)?

Comment: @Constructor - The rest of `[dcl.spec.auto]/10` actually addresses that. I didn't bring it in because you didn't ask about it in your posted question.

Comment: @Constructor - And there's also [\[dcl.spec.auto\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#8). It's different things, really. In a subtle way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and references! It looks like a sad story in fact.